# Laravel {{ auth()->user()->plan['name'] }} if empty

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I want that if someone has a plan its going to be shown
`{{  auth()->user()->plan['name']  }}`

but if the person doesnt has a plan it should be a text like "Demo"

how can I do this?

Comment: welcome Tim, the best way you can get help from stackoverflow is to show the little effort you have done, try out something and someone will help from there, from your question i think if you can show your database structure, your controller, then help will come.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `if` or a `ternary`

```
 {{ auth()->user()->plan['name'] ?  auth()->user()->plan['name'] : 'Demo' }}
```

Or

```
@if (auth()->user()->plan['name'])
    {{  auth()->user()->plan['name'] }}
@else
   Demo
@endif
```

Comment: or even `{{ auth()->user()->plan['name'] ?: 'Demo' }}`